# How to update state of parent component n level above in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Check the code here
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nandwana92/wrwsqob3/1/)

I wish to update the value property of individual item from the Child component. But as props are immutable and don't trigger re-render the code doesn't work. One way I know to make this work is pass a function from GrandParent to Parent and then to Child and use it to update state of GrandpParent. This will trigger re-render in the Child component. But this also causes re-render of GrandParent, Parent and other siblings of Child component.

```
// comment
```

Is there a better way to do this, this doesn't seem optimal to me.

Comment: if you're using redux best way is to use mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

Comment: +1 to previous comment - why not to use redux for that? If it doesn't fit - use  context. If it doesn't fit as well - you described everything yourself. Just manage re-rendering with keys and `shouldComponentUpdate`'

Comment: as mentioned by @donquixote you should use some architecture for this, it will be easy to handle all these kind of scenarios, maintain the data in store, and access it easily at any level.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like Redux is the way to go. Will explore.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.props.handleIncrement(e.currentTarget.dataset.key)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.props.item.value}</span>
        <button data-key={this.props.item.key} onClick={this.handleClick}>inc</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

class Parent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.list.map((item) => <Child item={item} handleIncrement={this.props.handleIncrement} />)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

}

class GrandParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [
        {
          key: 'one',
          value: 1
        },
        {
          key: 'two',
          value: 2
        },
        {
          key: 'three',
          value: 3
        }
      ]
    };

    this.handleIncrement = this.handleIncrement.bind(this)
  }

  handleIncrement(key) {
    this.setState({
        list: this.state.list.map((l) => {
        if (l.key === key) {
            return {key: l.key, value: l.value + 1}
        }
        return l
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (<Parent list={this.state.list} handleIncrement={this.handleIncrement} />);
  }

}

React.render(<GrandParent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

You have to pass the handler from the Grand parent and call this handler whenever you wanted to increment. Read about `coupling and cohesion` for theoretical background.

Answer (score 1):

React is based on the concept of unidirectional data flow. This means that your are passing data **down** to other components who receive it as props and render it, or passing it down to another sub component.

However, sometimes we want a child component to let a parent component that something happened. To solve this, we use callback. Callbacks are functions that we can pass as **props** to a child component, so he can use them we something happens. A classic example is to pass an `onClick` handler to a child component that has a button. Then, when the button is pushed the child component calls it like this:

```
this.props.onClick()
```

letting the parent know that the button was clicked. This will work for yor example too. Create a function in the GrandParent component that knows how to increment the value.

```
incrementValue = (idx) => {
    // Copy the list to avoid mutating the state itself.
    let newList = this.state.list.slice();
    newList[idx].value += 1;
    this.setState({list: newList});
}
```

Then pass this function as callback

```
<Parent onClick={this.incrementValue}/>
```

Then bind it to the button click like this:

```
<button onClick={this.props.onClick}>inc</button>
```

Read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) to learn more about state and props in React.